# Azure Devops Variables with embedded variables inside

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to have a variable with contains another variable inside it

for example

```
WebName  CoreCDS${Extension}
```

[image]

Comment: i was using {} instead of ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can enter your Varaible with `$(VariableName)` inside an another Variable.

`(Pipelines -> Library -> Variable Goups)`

[image]